# b2b freightquote shipping methods to woocommerce checkout via update_order_review

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue to update shipping methods on woocommerce checkout, when user change zip code.
I use woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review (standart woocommerce ajax action) to get ZIP code, and send it and products from cart to freightquote. This API can return big list of shipping methods:
http://b2b.freightquote.com/documents/Freightquote_API_Programmers_Reference.pdf
 (3 point)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'freightquote_get_methods' );
function freightquote_get_methods( $data ){
$Zip = /*billing_postcode from $data*/
$xml = /*some xml for api with $Zip, products etc.*/

$ch = curl_init('https://b2b.freightquote.com/WebService/QuoteService.asmx?WSDL');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch); //xml with methods if success
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

list of methods has more than 24 options (list can change every time after changing zip code in checkout form)

after parsing $output XML to an array, methods looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CarrierOptionId] => 1
            [CarrierName] => Frontline Freight (Consolidated Services)
            [SCAC] => FCSY
            [DOTNumber] => 2215162
            [QuoteAmount] => 332.95
            [Currency] => USD
            [IsGuaranteed] => false
            [IsTMS] => false
            [IsInterline] => false
            [Transit] => 7
            [TariffMultiplier] => 1
            [Mode] => Inter Direct
            [ProviderList] => Array
                (
                )

            [CarrierAccessorials] => Array
                (
                    [Accessorial] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccessorialId] => 158
                                    [AccessorialDescription] => Fuel surcharge
                                    [AccessorialCharge] => 69.41
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccessorialId] => 423
                                    [AccessorialDescription] => ARBITRARY ORIGIN CHARGE
                                    [AccessorialCharge] => 20
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

how to add those methods dynamically after changing zip? i cant create all classes, list of methods can change every time. right now i have 24 methods for my current query.